# Cannot set TwoWay mode to x:Bind

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need save position of UI element to variable. I put `x` and `y` to my collection and bind it

```
  <Canvas>
   <Grid
     Canvas.Top="{x:Bind PositionY, Mode=TwoWay}"
     Canvas.Left="{x:Bind PositionX, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And my 'model'

```
public double PositionX {get;set;}
public double PositionY {get;set;}
```

And I change it on page by moving and try to update these in collection
But if I set `Mode=TwoWay` I have compile **error**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Grid' does not contain a definition for 'Top' and no
>   extension method 'Top' accepting a first argument of type 'Grid' could
>   be found

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT yes, I did

Comment: I tested with the code you've posted, there is no compiler error in my side. The problem may not in the code you've posted. You can try with the code in a new Blank App project. If you still have problem, please share a [mcve].

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT hm, ok, I'll make blank app and test it again

Comment: Why would you do that? The grid never updates the Canval.Left rest Canvas.Top attached properties. Once you bind them to source properties (PositionX resp PositionY), then you should only change these source properties

Comment: @Liero PositionX and Y its start position on ViewModel and when Im drag my Grid( I have many small grids, its DataTemplate) I set new Canvas.Top and Left in my control that must update the collection. And I cannot change these properties from control

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT - you did test it in an UWP app, not in WPF, right? I can confirm the compile error.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes its uwp

Comment: @Smile: When you drag and drop, you should not update Canvas.Left, but ViewModel.PositionX and Canvas.Left is than automatically updated

Comment: @Liero not drag and drop, just drag on Page

Comment: It does not matter. Once you bind properties don't set them manually.

Comment: @Liero After set property i need update values in collection by view

Comment: You have to find a way how to update viewmodel values. Does not matter where the event occured, in a view or viewmodel

Comment: @Liero Microsoft already found it. TwoWay Binding. I use it for some different parts, but it doesn't work wits ui element position

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, Just created blank app and i have compile error. Thats my xaml code http://joxi.ru/eAOeN9asKR7Kmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler issue that has been fixed in Windows 10 Anniversary Update SDK (14393).

As we know, **[{x:Bind}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)** uses generated code to achieve its benefits. At XAML compile time, `{x:Bind}` is converted into code that will get a value from a property on a data source, and set it on the property specified in markup.

When the app targets earlier versions than 14393, it will generate code like following to update Two Way binding:

```
this.obj2 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid)target;
(this.obj2).RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas.LeftProperty,
    (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty prop) =>
    {
        if (this.initialized)
        {
            // Update Two Way binding
            this.dataRoot.PositionX = (this.obj2).Left;
        }
    });
(this.obj2).RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas.TopProperty,
    (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty prop) =>
    {
        if (this.initialized)
        {
            // Update Two Way binding
            this.dataRoot.PositionY = (this.obj2).Top;
        }
    });
```

`obj2` is a `Grid`, it does not contain a property called `Left` or `Top`, so we'll get compiler errors.

To fix this issue, the app's minimum target SDK version must be 14393 or later. To change the Minimum and Target version for a project that has already been created in Visual Studio, go to **Project  → Properties  → Application tab  → Targeting**.
[image]

After this, we can **Rebuild** the project, then there should be no compiler error. The binding should be generated correctly.

```
this.obj2 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid)target;
(this.obj2).RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas.LeftProperty,
    (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty prop) =>
    {
        if (this.initialized)
        {
            // Update Two Way binding
            this.dataRoot.PositionX = global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas.GetLeft(this.obj2);
        }
    });
(this.obj2).RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas.TopProperty,
    (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty prop) =>
    {
        if (this.initialized)
        {
            // Update Two Way binding
            this.dataRoot.PositionY = global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas.GetTop(this.obj2);
        }
    });
```